# How to share Google Analytics profile in new interface?

Tags: google-analytics

Since Google updated the interface of their Analytics service I can't seem to find a way to add users to the profiles I'm managing. Did some googling but only found threads with questions and no answers. Someone mentioned a gear icon but that seems to have gone missing in my dashboard. Googles own help files are useless. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to **Admin**.
2. Select the correct **Account** and click **User Management**.

   [image: User Management]
3. Then click **+ New User**. I'm sure you can take it from here ;)